# Getting this error on tap function to see an image in a dialog box

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

onTap: () {
showDialog(
context: context,
builder: (BuildContext context) {
return ImageNetwork(
image: data['image'].toString(),
height: 400,
width: 400,
duration: 1000,
curve: Curves.easeIn,
onPointer: true,
fitAndroidIos: BoxFit.cover,
fitWeb: BoxFitWeb.cover,
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
onLoading: const CircularProgressIndicator(
color: Colors.amber,
),
);
});

GET THIS ERROR:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your ImageNetwork() widget inside Material Widget

And set type to MaterialType.transparency

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => Material(
  type: MaterialType.transparency,
  child: YourWidget(...)
)
```

Comment: Working now, with this change

Answer (score 2):

```
Use Dialog widget over your ImageNetwork widget. This will resolve your issue.


onTap:() {
        showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Dialog(
           child: ImageNetwork(image: data['image'].toString(),
            height: 400,
            width: 400,
            duration: 1000,
            curve: Curves.easeIn,
            onPointer: true,
            fitAndroidIos: BoxFit.cover,
            fitWeb: BoxFitWeb.cover,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
            onLoading: const CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.amber,),),`enter code here`);
        });
      }
```